# Registering Django app for OAuth and Consuming API

Tags: python, django, oauth, openstreetmap

I've been creating a Django app, and *my current goal for it is to pull data from an API to my app*, the [Open Street Map API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) test service to be exact.

All of the API calls must be made by an authenticated and authorized user (via OAuth). So far I've made an OAuth account and they've given me values for my app (Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Request Token URL, Access Token URL, Authorise URL).

This is where my knowledge of OAuth and APIs comes to an end, as I have no idea how to continue to reach my goal. I have tried searching for a solution, but it seems every example I can find uses a version of Django that's too old and their steps are incompatible with my current version (Python 3.6 and Django 1.10).

Any help will be appreciated.

I haven't add much code to try this, simply because I don't know what to do.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'appName.apps.AppNameConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'oauth2_provider'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}
#The remainder is just generic Django settings...
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you already have. Remove your private data!

Comment: I did, although I haven't added much code to get this working since I don't know what to do next...

Comment: Just follow the example, here:  https://github.com/hotosm/osm-tasking-manager2/blob/0985cc87e47cf033db31a47afa567ce069872af5/osmtm/views/osmauth.py